# Hide Android Studio file path

Tags: android-studio

How can I hide the file path in android studio (it is captured on the screenshot)? I am talking about this:
app -> src -> main -> java -> com -> son...

Sorry for the stupid question but I didn't manage to find it it preferences and this path is not shown on my old mac with the same version of android studio.

[image: problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Mac, I am able to hide the file path by going to the View menu, then unchecking the checkbox next to "Navigation Bar".